# Wpf Datagrid: resize column from code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

in WPF i have a datagrid, populated with an ItemSource:

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myData;
```

I'd like to set the width of the column 0 to a specific width. If i type this code:

```
var tmp = myDataGrid.Columns;
```

why tmp is null?
How can i resize a specific column from code behind?

I put an image example: the datasource is "newListModel" that has 4 rows and each item has 3 columns. If i try to get the columns 0 i get an exception outofrange

[image]

I have only this in XAML for the definition of the datagrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridListe" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,303,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="155" Width="676" CanUserAddRows="False" MouseDoubleClick="dataGridListe_MouseDoubleClick"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity ...why oh why are you trying to set the width from the code ? The power and beauty of WPF is using the XAML (usually binding to properties ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the columns in the XAML also set the AutoGenerateColumns to be False.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridListe" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>                
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="YourProperty1" Binding="{Binding Path=YourProperty1}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="YourProperty2" Binding="{Binding Path=YourProperty2}"/>
            ....
           </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

Then, You need to specify the index of the column

```
DataGridColumn column = dataGridListe.Columns[0];
column.Width = 200;
```

Comment: That doesn't answer "why tmp is null?", and *if* `tmp` really *is* `null`, should yield a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: With that code i get an outofrange exception and i don't understand why!!

Comment: @Tom can you post your XAML

Comment: Posted. Anyway the datasource is displayed correctly inside the datagrid. The problem is i try to get the reference to the column

Comment: @Tom check modified answer